# Use cases for Passing class members as arguments to randomize() function from ASIC verification application perspective

Tags: system-verilog

Also, in which context passing "null" argument is needed?
Please refer section 18.11 in SV LRM.

```
  class CA;
    rand byte x, y;
    byte v, w;
    constraint c1 { x < v && y > w );
  endclass

  CA a = new;
  a.randomize(); // random variables: x, y state variables: v, w
  a.randomize( x ); // random variables: x state variables: y, v, w
  a.randomize( v, w ); // random variables: v, w state variables: x, y
  a.randomize( w, x ); // random variables: w, x state variables: y, v
```

How to use this feature in testbench or what are use cases for this language feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have a particular test that needs the variable `y` fixed to the value 5. SystemVerilog gives you ***4*** different ways of accomplishing this!

With the method shown above, you would set `y=5` before calling randomize:

```
y=5;
a.randomize( x ); // y becomes a state variable
```

Realistically, this method is rarely used unless you have a very small set of random variables to deal with. I've never seen anyone try to randomize a non-random variable this way.

Another method is setting the rand_mode

```
y=5;
a.y.rand_mode(0); // y becomes a state variable
a.randomize();
```

You do have to remember to set the rand_mode(1) if needed.
However the simplest method is using the `with` constraint.

```
a.randomize() with {y==5;};
```

But the problem with all of the above methods is it requires modifying procedural code. The Object-Oriented-Programming(OOP) approach is extending the class.

```
class YCA extends CA;
  constraint y5 {y==5;}
endclass
```

And to answer your last question, `randomize(null)` is used simply to check that the current values of all the random variables meet the constraints without actually randomizing anything. This is useful for debugging.